# In React, what is the function of the key attribute in html tag

Tags: reactjs

What is the function of the key attribute in the p tag? I inspected the dom, and I expected to see p tags for each element of the taco list as expressed in `<p taco-1>`, but it's just `<p>`. Any explanation will be much appreciated.

```
{this.props.tacos.map( ( taco, i ) => {
    return <p key={ `taco-${ i }` }>{ taco }</p>;
})}
```

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding unique keys for array children in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28329382/understanding-unique-keys-for-array-children-in-react-js)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It is used by React in a collection of component to see which element is inserted, which element is removed and which element is updated. Without the `key` attribute, it's hard to determine how to update the collection.

For example, see component collection below:

```
<ul>
    <li>England</li>
    <li>France</li>
</ul>
```

and then next state tells React to render:

```
<ul>
    <li>England</li>
    <li>Germany</li>
</ul>
```

There's multiple ways to update the DOM:

- Change inner text of second `<li>`
- Remove second `<li>` and add a new one

Without key, React don't know which one to choose.

You can read more in the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys).

Comment: Curious why there is no such need for static html

Comment: A better example is given in this lnk https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#recursing-on-children